# How can we catch the upgrade http request from Nestjs Gateway (websockets)

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs, ws

In order to implement manually an authentication process with websockets in NestJS, I'm using a NestJS Gateway but have troubles setting up a handler for the "upgrade" http request that is sent during the handshake before the connection of the websocket. Is there a way to set up somewhere a function that can enable me to catch this request so I can deny access asap?

This would allow to stop the process sooner and that no socket can be opened if there is no valid auth token in the http request.
I found that I can validate the socket aftewards using the protocol field of a websocket instance (the client just sets a second parameter on websocket connection), but I prefer not having to deal with "bad" sockets to close just after their connection and stop them on the initial handshake through http, whatever the process.

Answer (score 1):

The best example I have seen of doing this is here: https://github.com/mauricekraus/nestjs-ws-wrapper

Note that the example works, but the package seems to be missing some dependencies in package.json.

He is authenticating with a JWT, but I believe you could adapt the approach easily enough.

From the description:

> This project tries to prevent a websocket connection from being established if a user is not properly authenticated (before the connection event, but on upgrade).

And under Usage

> Just inherit from the base class (SocketGateway) and if you want to have your sockets authenticated, create an init method and decorate it with @SocketInit() and call the authentication method.

```
@SocketInit()
  public initTest(request: IncomingMessage) {
    return this.authenticate(request);
  }
```